# Javascript check for native placeholder support in IE8

Tags: javascript, placeholder

**tldr:**
Why does ('placeholder' in inputElemnt) equal true in IE8 despite no native support for the placeholder attribute? Isn't (attribute in element) a good way to check for native support? The Javascript library Modernizer use it.

**Long:**
<del>I have a small Jquery plugin called Defaultvalue ( http://unwrongest.com/projects/defaultvalue/ ).</del> I have a small Jquery plugin called Placeholder ( https://github.com/janjarfalk/jquery.placeholder.js ). It's basically a fallback for the HTML5 placeholder attribute.

In a recent updated I added these three lines of code. Hoping that Defaultvalue wouldn't run if the browser had native support for the placeholder attribute.

```
if('placeholder' in this){
    // this is an input-element
    return false;
}
```

It seems to work in most browsers except IE8 and IE7. For some reason it finds the key 'placeholder' in this, but there isn't, I think, any support for the placeholder attribute in IE7/IE8.

My code was inspired by this code in the Javascript library Modernizer ( http://www.modernizr.com/ ).

```
(function(props) {
    for (var i = 0, len = props.length; i < len; i++) {
        attrs[ props[i] ] = !!(props[i] in inputElem);
    }
    return attrs;
})('autocomplete autofocus list placeholder max min multiple pattern required step'.split(' '));
```

What am I missing?

Comment: IE is clueless about attributes and properties, it thinks they are the same thing (as does jQuery). Non-standard attributes are added as "expando" properties. Using for..in to iterate over the properties of host objects is not a good idea. IE < 9 doesn't support hasAttribute, so that won't work either.

Comment: The placeholder attribute is not implemented in IE9 either...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Creating a new raw input element solved my problem.

```
var nativePlaceholderSupport = (function() {
    var i = document.createElement('input');
    return i.placeholder !== undefined;
})();

if(nativePlaceholderSupport){
    return false;
}
```

```
var nativePlaceholderSupport = (function(){
    var i = document.createElement('input');
    return ('placeholder' in i);
})();

if(nativePlaceholderSupport){
    return false;
}
```

Thanks RobG, you led me to it.

Comment: That is not a good solution.  The HTML5 **draft** says: "The attribute, if specified, ...", so it isn't a mandatory attribute and there is no reason to believe an element will have a placeholder property if the attribute hasn't been set. Therefore, its absence is not an indication that it isn't supported, only that it hasn't been set. And don't use for..in on host objects, whatever you are trying to do can likely be solved some other way that is supported by a wider selection of browsers.

Comment: @RobG He's not using for...in.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Ok, if..in, whatever. This is similar to the debate about native object properties being returned in a specific order because some browsers to it that way, even though ECMA-262 says not to rely on it. If something is defined in a spec you can expect that over time browsers will converge on that behaviour and deal with the exceptions. If a behaviour is common but not specified, you are just hoping everyone follows the leader. Maybe they will, maybe they wont. They don't all follow IE in regard to object property order, so why follow Gecko/WebKit on DOM attribute/properties?

Comment: @RobG This is not a Gecko/WebKit thing. This is cross-browser, it's just how browsers work. [Take a look at this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Hsjaf/1/). The rule is: If the browser implements property X on DOM elements of type Y, then **every** DOM element of type Y will contain property X regardless of whether or not attribute X has been set on the corresponding HTML element in the HTML source code. If no attribute is defined, then the value of the corresponding property will be falsy (`""`, `false`, `0`, etc.), but the property **will exist** on that DOM element.

Comment: While browser behaviour is evidence, it isn't enough on its own to convince me. A search of relevant W3C drafts shows that indeed, at least as far as HTML5 is concerned, browsers should create properties on DOM elements for all supported attributes even if they have not be assigned a value or aren't present in the markup.

Comment: Regardless of the specifications from W3C, the presence of the attribute is the only thing we can rely on to proberly determine the browsers ability to support the property. So until a browser decides to  deviate that much from the other browsers, I personally think this is a reliable way of testing it. However i would probably use `i.placeholder !== undefined` for testing the existence of the property, as it impacts performance a little less.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. It equals to false in both IE9 and IE8.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JVSgx/

Comment: Does IE 9 support the placeholder attribute? As far as I know it doesn't.

Comment: @RobG No. My demo confirms that.