# Placeholder not working for Internet Explorer

Tags: html

Placeholder for my textbox in below format is not working for Internet Explorer. Is there anyway to display placeholder for TextBox in Internet Explorer?

`<asp:TextBox id="email" runat="server" width="300" placeholder="Your email" />`

Is there any simple way just by using any JavaScript. I am not interested to make it complicated using jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120257/what-is-the-best-html5-placeholder-like-jquery-plugin-out-there

Comment: Change line #11 to: if (!curInput.type || curInput.type == "" || curInput.type == "text" || curInput.type == "password") ...and it works for password fields as well!

Comment: [The placeholder attribute **should not** be used as an alternative to a label.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute)

Comment: 'I am not interested to make it complicated using jQuery' - I'd argue the accepted solution is significantly more complex than the equivalent jquery.

Comment: Only if you are already including jQuery.

Comment: For anyone coming to this question now, a couple of years after it was asked, please note that (a) IE10 and up have full support for the `placeholder` attribute, and (b) numerous polyfills scripts [are available from here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder).

Comment: According to caniuse: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can imitate this using pure JavaScript:

```
var _debug = false;
var _placeholderSupport = function() {
    var t = document.createElement("input");
    t.type = "text";
    return (typeof t.placeholder !== "undefined");
}();

window.onload = function() {
    var arrInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var arrTextareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
    var combinedArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++)
        combinedArray.push(arrInputs[i]);
    for (var i = 0; i < arrTextareas.length; i++)
        combinedArray.push(arrTextareas[i]);
    for (var i = 0; i < combinedArray.length; i++) {
        var curInput = combinedArray[i];
        if (!curInput.type || curInput.type == "" || curInput.type == "text" || curInput.type == "textarea")
            HandlePlaceholder(curInput);
        else if (curInput.type == "password")
            ReplaceWithText(curInput);
    }

    if (!_placeholderSupport) {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
            var oForm = document.forms[i];
            if (oForm.attachEvent) {
                oForm.attachEvent("onsubmit", function() {
                    PlaceholderFormSubmit(oForm);
                });
            }
            else if (oForm.addEventListener)
                oForm.addEventListener("submit", function() {
                    PlaceholderFormSubmit(oForm);
                }, false);
        }
    }
};

function PlaceholderFormSubmit(oForm) {    
    for (var i = 0; i < oForm.elements.length; i++) {
        var curElement = oForm.elements[i];
        HandlePlaceholderItemSubmit(curElement);
    }
}

function HandlePlaceholderItemSubmit(element) {
    if (element.name) {
        var curPlaceholder = element.getAttribute("placeholder");
        if (curPlaceholder && curPlaceholder.length > 0 && element.value === curPlaceholder) {
            element.value = "";
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                element.value = curPlaceholder;
            }, 100);
        }
    }
}

function ReplaceWithText(oPasswordTextbox) {
    if (_placeholderSupport)
        return;
    var oTextbox = document.createElement("input");
    oTextbox.type = "text";
    oTextbox.id = oPasswordTextbox.id;
    oTextbox.name = oPasswordTextbox.name;
    //oTextbox.style = oPasswordTextbox.style;
    oTextbox.className = oPasswordTextbox.className;
    for (var i = 0; i < oPasswordTextbox.attributes.length; i++) {
        var curName = oPasswordTextbox.attributes.item(i).nodeName;
        var curValue = oPasswordTextbox.attributes.item(i).nodeValue;
        if (curName !== "type" && curName !== "name") {
            oTextbox.setAttribute(curName, curValue);
        }
    }
    oTextbox.originalTextbox = oPasswordTextbox;
    oPasswordTextbox.parentNode.replaceChild(oTextbox, oPasswordTextbox);
    HandlePlaceholder(oTextbox);
    if (!_placeholderSupport) {
        oPasswordTextbox.onblur = function() {
            if (this.dummyTextbox && this.value.length === 0) {
                this.parentNode.replaceChild(this.dummyTextbox, this);
            }
        };
    }
}

function HandlePlaceholder(oTextbox) {
    if (!_placeholderSupport) {
        var curPlaceholder = oTextbox.getAttribute("placeholder");
        if (curPlaceholder && curPlaceholder.length > 0) {
            Debug("Placeholder found for input box '" + oTextbox.name + "': " + curPlaceholder);
            oTextbox.value = curPlaceholder;
            oTextbox.setAttribute("old_color", oTextbox.style.color);
            oTextbox.style.color = "#c0c0c0";
            oTextbox.onfocus = function() {
                var _this = this;
                if (this.originalTextbox) {
                    _this = this.originalTextbox;
                    _this.dummyTextbox = this;
                    this.parentNode.replaceChild(this.originalTextbox, this);
                    _this.focus();
                }
                Debug("input box '" + _this.name + "' focus");
                _this.style.color = _this.getAttribute("old_color");
                if (_this.value === curPlaceholder)
                    _this.value = "";
            };
            oTextbox.onblur = function() {
                var _this = this;
                Debug("input box '" + _this.name + "' blur");
                if (_this.value === "") {
                    _this.style.color = "#c0c0c0";
                    _this.value = curPlaceholder;
                }
            };
        }
        else {
            Debug("input box '" + oTextbox.name + "' does not have placeholder attribute");
        }
    }
    else {
        Debug("browser has native support for placeholder");
    }
}

function Debug(msg) {
    if (typeof _debug !== "undefined" && _debug) {
        var oConsole = document.getElementById("Console");
        if (!oConsole) {
            oConsole = document.createElement("div");
            oConsole.id = "Console";
            document.body.appendChild(oConsole);
        }
        oConsole.innerHTML += msg + "<br />";
    }
}
```

This will do nothing if the browser is already supporting the `placeholder` attribute, and in case it's not supported (e.g. the browser is IE) it will add very similar functionality - text shown by default that disappear on focus and appears again if user didn't type anything.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/S5J7u/389/).

**Bug Fixes**

*Nov 6, 2012*: Previous code failed to detect when browser didn't have native support for placeholder. Using code found [in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536236/javascript-check-for-native-placeholder-support-in-ie8) it's now fixed. Affected browsers: IE7 and IE8, maybe others as well. Also added debug support to help debug future problems.

*Jan 30, 2013*:

1. Adding support for password input as well. Since IE8 and below won't allow dynamic change of input type, the code is replacing the password input with text input as long as there is no password typed, thus the placeholder text will be visible.
2. Fixed bug that caused the placeholder value to be sent where empty value should be sent to the server when the form associated with the input is being submitted. To achieve this, code is attached to the form submit event and clear the value if needed.

*Jan 24, 2014*: adding support for `<textarea>` elements.

Comment: Wow thanks, I went around the entire internet looking for a placeholder fallback that works in IE. Finally, this is the one.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This doesn't work in IE7 or IE8 for me. It works in IE9, but doesn't work on password inputs.

Comment: @Mark sorry for delay, didn't get notification for your comment. Bug found and fixed, it works now on those browsers as well. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @ZainShaikh hopefully my fix will solve the issue for that browser as well, I don't have access to such browser so please let me know. If still not working please change to `_debug = true;` and post here the debug results. Thanks!

Comment: Sir You have done me a great service with this script, I have been toiling for days to solve this issue and with a beautiful script that all required of me was to cut and paste and boom.  it works.  I cannot thank you enough!!

Comment: I placed this code on my site, but it stopped working when I had to call two other scripts in my body tag.  I think the window.onload is being overwritten? how can I stop this?

Comment: @Trevor quick fix would be to place the call to those two other scripts inside the onload function i.e. after the line `window.onload = function() {`. Proper fix would be to attach event listener instead of overriding the onload, will do it soon and edit this post.

Comment: i wanted to show a placeholder for a textarea.  i copy pasted the above code.  even though there is placeholder attribute for that control, it is not showing up, am i missing something?

Comment: @user1447718 thanks, simple oversight on my side, added support for textarea now. Let me know if you still have any problems. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of polyfill scripts written that will add placeholder support to browsers that don't natively support the technology.

Rather than repeating what's been written elsewhere, I'd recommend going here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills and scroll down about 1/3 of the way to the section entitled **Web Forms : input placeholder** for a few different options (both native JS and jQuery). Since that entire page is curated by the HTML5 Boilerplate team you can be fairly certain that the scripts provided are of decent quality.

Edit: just saw your comment about not using HTML5. The scripts on the link I provided *should* still work even if you're not using the HTML5 doctype (no guarantees expressed or implied, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

I have written this simple code, and it worked fine for me when tested:

```
placeholder=function(){
    $('input, textarea').each(function(){
        var holder=$(this).attr('placeholder');
        if(typeof(holder) !=='undefined'){
            $(this).val(holder);
            $(this).bind('click',function(){
                $(this).val('');
            }).blur(function(){
                $(this).val(holder);
            });
        }
    });
};
$(document).ready(placeholder);
```

Comment: Your code is working in ie,but making issue in FF and GC browsers that is the placeholder text becomes bold and if i click that the normal font appears in input box,i am not bale to see the entered data.For debuging I removed the DOM ready from bottom and added at top,the issue in FF & GC seems fine but placeholder not in IE.

Comment: Excellent stuff! But I've put the function initialisation into a condition like `if( $.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= '9.0' )`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder is an HTML5 feature. To work around I detect MSIE and do this:

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
    $("#textarea-id").val('placeholder');
    $("#textarea-id").focus(function(){
        this.select();
    });
}
```

Its jquery but not that complicated...

Comment: It might not be that complicated, but why use a 31kB library only for this expletively simple task? A few hundred bytes of pure JS seems cleaner to me :)

Comment: @Madcoder. if you are using placeholder, you are using HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue recently - I use modernizr to detect html5 features and then run a bit of js for the browsers that can't cope:

```
    function addPlaceHolder(input) {//using modernizr add placeholder text for non html5 users
    if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) { 
        input.focus(function () {
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
                input.removeClass('placeholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.addClass('placeholder');
                input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
            }
        }).blur();
        $(input).parents('form').submit(function () {
            $(this).find(input).each(function () {
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                }
            })
        });
    }
}

addPlaceHolder($('#Myinput'));
```

seems to work well for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [JavaScript Polyfill](http://www.moreonfew.com/what-are-polyfills-in-javascript/) to make the placeholder work on older browsers. There are many Polyfills out there. Here is one that talks about [Making Placeholders work in IE](http://www.moreonfew.com/how-to-make-placeholder-work-in-ie/). Basically what all these Scripts do is to Simulate the behaviour of a native placeholder support of browser using JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Just grabbed the code from above and made it more generic

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function addPlaceHolder(input) {

    if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
        input.focus(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                $(this).val('');
                $(this).removeClass('placeholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                $(this).addClass('placeholder');
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
            }
        }).blur();
        $(input).parents('form').submit(function () {
            $(this).find(input).each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            })
        });
     }
 }

    addPlaceHolder($(':text'));
    addPlaceHolder($('textarea'));

</script>
```

Comment: The original post stated that he didn't want to use jQuery.