# placeholder-not-working-for-internet-explorer if input type is password, still its showing the *********

Tags: javascript

I got 1 answer at [Placeholder not working for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628522/placeholder-not-working-for-internet-explorer)

and i am using this code,

```
window.onload = function() { 
    var arrInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) { 
        var curInput = arrInputs[i]; 
        if (!curInput.type || curInput.type == "" || curInput.type == "text"|||| curInput.type == "password") 
            HandlePlaceholder(curInput); 
    } 
}; 



function HandlePlaceholder(oTextbox) { 
    if (typeof oTextbox.placeholder == "undefined") { 
        var curPlaceholder = oTextbox.getAttribute("placeholder"); 
        if (curPlaceholder && curPlaceholder.length > 0) { 
            oTextbox.value = curPlaceholder; 
            oTextbox.setAttribute("old_color", oTextbox.style.color); 
            oTextbox.style.color = "#c0c0c0"; 
            oTextbox.onfocus = function() { 
                this.style.color = this.getAttribute("old_color"); 
                if (this.value === curPlaceholder) 
                    this.value = ""; 
            }; 
            oTextbox.onblur = function() { 
                if (this.value === "") { 
                    this.style.color = "#c0c0c0"; 
                    this.value = curPlaceholder; 
                } 
            }; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

that's great, but now i am getting a problem, where in place of showing "password", it's showing ******** special symbol, is there any way to resolve this

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to accurately polyfill the `placeholder` attribute in all browsers. This is one of the reasons. You can't change the `type` of an `input` element. [Placeholders.js](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) attempts to be as comprehensive as possible, but it still can't do passwords properly in IE (they work well in other browsers though).

Comment: @JamesAllardice: A possible solution would be to change the `type` attribute of the `input` elements when they're focused and blurred. I'd just drop support for old versions of IE and leave the nicer features for users with compliant browsers.

Comment: @Blender - That is exactly what Placeholders.js does :) see my answer.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: And IE still manages to get around it!

Comment: @Blender - Yeah there's nothing you can do to make it work properly in IE, short of creating a new element, which is a route I don't want to take in the polyfill really. I've spent many hours fighting with IE to get that polyfill to the state it's in now!

Comment: @user1722288 - There are numerous other problems with your existing code... for example, if the user doesn't enter a value, the placeholder text is going to be submitted as part of the form.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can resolve it is to use another element (hide the original, or lay a new one on top). Unfortuantely, Internet Explorer does not allow you to change the `type` attribute of an `input` element. This code (from my `placeholder` polyfill, [Placeholders.js](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js)) demonstrates the problem:

```
if (element.type === "password") {
    // The `type` property is read-only in IE < 9, so in those cases we just move on. The placeholder will be displayed masked
    try {
        element.type = "text";
        element.setAttribute("data-placeholdertype", "password");
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

This means we can support all browsers except IE very well. Unless you want to create a new element (that's not a route I want to take in the polyfill), you'll have to live with it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder param is not supported in IE 9 and lower:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

(I guess that's why you wrote your own stuff)

The only option is to change the `type="password"` to `type="text"` when displaying the placeholder and change it back when the placeholder is removed.

You can also use one of the long list of [polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) (section: Web Forms : input placeholder)

Comment: See my answer - you can't change the `type` in IE.

Comment: right.. stupid IE.. if you really still want it, go radical and remove the whole element and create a new.. that should work... (don't forget to set the properties and listeners again)

Comment: Yeah, that's really your only option in IE. Which is why in Placeholders.js I just ignore it and leave IE to display the placeholder as masked text :(