# Angularjs input[placeholder] directive breaking with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So first day on the job with angularjs and i'm not quite getting it. I'm trying to mimic an html5 placeholder using an angular directive. It totally works until I add an ng-model to the field and then it only works after a user interacts with the field and also breaks any value the field had.

code up here
http://jsbin.com/esujax/32/edit

---

#### the directive

```
App.directive('placehold', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var insert = function() {
        element.val(attrs.placehold);
      };

      element.bind('blur', function(){
        if(element.val() === '')
          insert();
      });

      element.bind('focus', function(){
        if(element.val() === attrs.placehold)
          element.val('');
      });

      if(element.val() === '')
        insert();
    }
  }
});
```

#### the html

```
<textarea ng-model="comment" placehold="with a model it doesn't work"></textarea>
```

---

seems super simple but i'm lost

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just few modifications in your sample:

```
app.directive('placehold', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {      

      var value;

      var placehold = function () {
          element.val(attr.placehold)
      };
      var unplacehold = function () {
          element.val('');
      };

      scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function (val) {
        value = val || '';
      });

      element.bind('focus', function () {
         if(value == '') unplacehold();
      });

      element.bind('blur', function () {
         if (element.val() == '') placehold();
      });

      ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (val) {
        if (!val) {
          placehold();
          value = '';
          return attr.placehold;
        }
        return val;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

You can test it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/8m54JO?p=preview

Not sure, that it is the best solution, anyway it works. Even if you type the same text, that you have in your placehold attribute, cause it checks the model's value on focus.

Comment: do i have to have a controller and add the value to scope to do this. the way i thought of it a directive should be reusable on any element?

Comment: You are right, my fault. Fixed it to work without initial value: http://plnkr.co/edit/8m54JO?p=preview

Comment: this will cause memory leasks, dont forget to unbind the events!

Answer (score 2):

You can also checkout an Angular.JS module that implements the "placeholder" attribute for older web browsers:

https://github.com/urish/angular-placeholder-shim

Answer (score 0):

I have created a placeholder directive that can take angularjs expressions and also hides the placeholder text on input.  You can read about the placeholder at http://blog.f1circle.com/2013/09/supporting-placeholders-in-non-html5.html

Here is the gist.

```
(function(angular, app) {
  "use strict";
  app.directive('placeholder',["$document", "$timeout", function($document, $timeout){
    var link = function(scope,element,attrs,ctrl){

      // if you dont use modernizr library use the solution given at
      // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536236/javascript-check-for-native-placeholder-support-in-ie8
      // to check if placeholder is supported natively
      if(Modernizr.input.placeholder){
        return;
      }

      /*
        The following keys all cause the caret to jump to the end of the input value
        27,  Escape
        33,  Page up
        34,  Page down
        35,  End
        36,  Home
        Arrow keys allow you to move the caret manually, which should be prevented when the placeholder is visible
        37,  Left
        38,  Up
        39,  Right
        40,  Down
        The following keys allow you to modify the placeholder text by removing characters, which should be prevented when the placeholder is visible
        8,  Backspace
        46  Delete
      */

      var pTxt, modelValue, placeholding = false, badKeys = [27,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,8,46];

      var unplacehold = function(){
        if(!placeholding){
          return;
        }
        placeholding = false;
        element.removeClass('placeholder');
        element.val('');
      };

      var placehold = function(){
        if(placeholding || modelValue){
          return;
        }
        placeholding = true;
        element.addClass('placeholder');
        element.val(pTxt);
      };

      var moveCaret = function(elem, index) {
        var range;
        if (elem.createTextRange) {
          range = elem.createTextRange();
          range.move("character", index);
          range.select();
        } else if (elem.selectionStart) {
          elem.focus();
          elem.setSelectionRange(index, index);
        }
      };

      attrs.$observe('placeholder',function(value){
        pTxt = value;
        placeholding = false;
        placehold();
      });

      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value){
        modelValue = value;
        if(!value){
          placehold();
        }
        if(placeholding){
          return '';
        }
        return value;
      });

      ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (value){
        if(!value){
          placehold();
          modelValue = '';
          return pTxt;
        }
        return value;
      });

      element.on('click focus contextmenu',function(event){
        if($document[0].activeElement  !== this){
          return;
        }

        if(!modelValue){
          moveCaret(this,0);
        }
      });

      element.on('blur',function(){
        placehold();
      });

      element.on('keydown',function(e){
        if(!placeholding){
          return;
        }
        if(_.contains(badKeys,e.keyCode)){
          if(e.preventDefault){
            e.preventDefault();
          }
          return false;
        }
        unplacehold();
      });

      element.on('keyup',function(e){
        if(modelValue){
          return;
        }
        placehold();
        moveCaret(this,0);
      });

      element.on('paste',function(e){
        $timeout(function(){
          modelValue = element.val();
        },0);

      });
    };

    return{
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link : link,
      priority:3,
    };
  }]);
})(angular, app);
```

This works on all cases except when copy and paste the same placeholder text.